# Why do we need to override run() method extending thread class

Tags: java

Why do we need to override `run` method of `thread` class when extending it. As long as I know when we extend a class we override methods which are abstract. But run method has definition public void main(). Why is it mandatory to override it.

Answer (score 2):

The essence of a thread is that it runs something... So the Thread abstraction naturally would require you to provide something to run. This is accomplished in Java by requiring you to implement run().

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()

Because Thread implements Runnable and it has a run() method which does not have ANY implementation (They cannot predict what you want to "run")

Hence when you extend the Thread class , you need to override the run() method

P.S: You can create a class which extends Thread class and Does NOT override run() method, java will not throw any error, but when you start the Thread you will be just executing an empty implementation (so basically nothing)

Answer (score 1):

When we extend a class, we do not override just the abstract methods. Overriding is what we do when we need to provide a more specific implementation of a particular parent class method in the child class. The reason why we override `run` when we extend the thread class is that we want some piece of code to run in a multi-threaded fashion. So the creators of Java have agreed upon a name for the method to be overridden. Else every developer would use his/her own names for the method and the compiler would not know where the multi-threaded code is.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a thread for some purpose. To achieve that purpose you have to write a code.

In `run()` of `Thread` class, the implementation does nothing. You have add your own logic to achieve your purpose. Simply override `run()` write your logic in it and its done.

Now if you have question that **why Java did not keep this `run()` as abstract method** then please see post [Why is Thread not an abstract class and start() not final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202946/why-is-thread-not-an-abstract-class-and-start-not-final/31203979)